# Bash how to store in a variable the result of a linux command?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to store in a variable the temperature of the computer. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
temp = cat "/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp"
echo "$temp"
```

i tried this too:

```
#!/bin/bash
temp = $(cat "/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp")
echo "$temp"
```

but nothing works, it always says

```
./temp.sh: line 2: temp: command not found
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Spaces are crucial! This works fine:

```
# NO space around `=`
temp=$(cat "/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp")
echo "$temp"
```

Comment: Consider the usual chiding (re: the *Answer Well-Asked Questions* section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) advising that new instances of frequently-asked questions be closed, not answered) to have taken place.